# PHP: Can't access imported ini values

Tags: php, ini

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I'm new to PHP and can't figure it out. I'm trying to parse a .ini file, which works correctly, but I somehow can't access the values.

My site is structured like this:

```
project/
    index.php
    inc/
        init.php
        classes/
            frontend.php
    msg/
        messages.ini
```

The messages file is parsed in `init.php` with `$messages = parse_ini_file("msg/messages.ini");` and then included in `index.php` like this:

```
<?php
require_once('inc/init.php');

//printing the array here works!

$html = new frontend();
```

If I print the messages array from `index.php` everything works fine.

Yet when the `index.php` builds the `new frontend();` the `$messages` array is not available there. The `frontend` itself is loaded in `init.php` and works fine without the ini file.

Thus I assume there is an import or variable scope issue, but I can't figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: show the code of `frontend()`

Comment: @MArcinOrlowski It is building the frontend, which works correctly. I'm trying to outsource some (currently hard-coded) messages.

Comment: Scope Scope Scope http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$html = new frontend();
```

... do something like:

```
$html = new frontend($messages);
```

PHP [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is rather simple anyway: a variable is either global or local to a function/method.

Comment: I thought about passing the array as an argument, but shouldn't it have at least the same scope as the frontend if it is included in index.php?

Comment: Scope is not so complex. There isn't a per-block or per-file scope.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work now. This also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring `$messages` as global inside `frontend()`.

Comment: do not use `global`. This is bad coding style

Comment: Why would it be bad coding style?